# loop inside (append of another loop)

Tags: jquery, ajax, xml

I'm trying to import **XML** data as an `<ul>` inside an **HTML** file using jQuery **Ajax**.

My **XML** file structure as the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<playlist>
    <audio>
        <url></url>
        <title></title>
        <artist></artist>
        <labels>
            <label></label>
            <label></label>
            <label></label>
        </labels>
    </audio>
    <audio>
        /* another data */
    </audio>
<playlist>
```

My **HTML** is:

```
<div id="container">
    <ul class="playlist"></ul>
</div>
```

## This is my jQuery try:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "playlist.xml",
    dataType: "xml",
    success: xmlParser
    });
});


function xmlParser(xml) {
    $(xml).find("audio").each(function () {
        $("ul.playlist").append(
            '<li><a href="'
            + $(this).find("url").text()
            + '"><b>'
            + $(this).find("title").text()
            + '</b> - '
            + $(this).find("artist").text();


//==============================================
            $(this).find("labels").children("label").each(function () {
                    '<span class="label">' + $(this).text() +'</span>'
            })
//==============================================


            + '</a></li>'
        );
    });
}
```

---

Now, the problem between the comment lines:

I don't know how to insert another loop (each loop) here?

- How can I insert append inside append?
- If I used **append** to write the loop output, what element I'm supposed to append it to?

Any ideas how can I do it?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I add this as a comment, because it's not an answer to your question, but two different alternatives: 1) XSLT, which directly transforms XML into HTML:  http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/xsl_client.asp 2) Parse the XML as a JS object, or better than this, return JSON from the server, which is easyly parsed to a JavaScript object, and use some templating library like handlebars.js: http://handlebarsjs.com/ I don't know which possibilities you have to implement this alternatives, but both are quite useful. It's much easier to learn the second option.

Comment: Many thanks for these notes/suggestions @JotaBe! will check them. highly appreciated comment for sure!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your looping logic is fine. You simply need to append to the string within the second loop, instead of having one long concatenation. Try this:

```js
$(xml).find("audio").each(function () {
    var html = '<li><a href="' + $(this).find("url").text() + '">' + 
        '<b>' + $(this).find("title").text() + '</b> - ' + $(this).find("artist").text();

    $(this).find("labels").children("label").each(function () {
        html += '<span class="label">' + $(this).text() +'</span>'
    })

    html += '</a></li>'

    $("ul.playlist").append(html);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

try this:-

```
function xmlParser(xml) {
$(xml).find("audio").each(function () {
     var labels= "";
     $(this).find("labels").children("label").each(function () {             
         labels+= '<span class="label">' + $(this).text() +'</span>';             
     })
    $("ul.playlist").append(
        '<li><a href="'
        + $(this).find("url").text()
        + '"><b>'
        + $(this).find("title").text()
        + '</b> - '
        + $(this).find("artist").text()   +labels    + '</a></li>'
    );
});
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/qg5khnm2/)